# Background image on IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

How to show background image on IE 8.

**Html**

```
 <div id="header"></div>
```

**Css**

```
#header
 {
 background-image:url('../img/header.png');
 height:73px;
 }
```

Comment: I don't have IE8 so i can't test but try `background-image:` and if that doesn't work make sure the path of the image is correct

Comment: @jmore009 On chrome and Firefox background image show correctly.But nothing show on  IE 8.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache in IE?

Comment: @setek Yes same result.

Comment: What happens when you put some text into the `<div>`?

Comment: I need to check why my background not showing on IE 8 this is my question.If i write any thing in div Simple this should be show.That is not my question.

Comment: It's part of debugging. I asked the question because I thought perhaps your `div` was not actually taking up any space, e.g. if it is set to `display: inline;` You don't need to respond like that, I'm trying to help you.

Comment: @Vucko : What??? `#header` wont work in IE8?

Comment: @RoyMJ My bad, didn't saw it's a `div` (just saw the `header` part). I need coffee :)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving some width like `width:960px`

Normally, IE8 wont take width default if some other class is inherit floating like `float:left`. Or you can remove float to display the background image.

You also mentioned in the comment, that the background is showing when adding some text. So I'm sure the problem is with your width;

Answer (score 0):

Normally it works fine no matter what browser you use, its a basic css attribute. Did you try simple "background" attribute instead of "background-image" or may be check the path of the image you are calling  in as the background

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
#header{
   background: url('../img/header.png') no-repeat left top; //Assuming path is correct since it works in other browsers
   height:73px;
   width: 1000px;// Give width here
   float: left;
}
```